# What's Bitcoin url or where can I find it

Tags: transactions

What is a Bitcoin transaction url? Is that the wallet or hash or what. I sent btc to address for game n it says confirmed but never came. Now the host is asking for transaction url but ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a Bitcoin transaction URL. Bitcoin transactions are identified by a transaction-ID which looks like 31144ef6faaad902f3ec4e6f6241aa09f9ea08374abb67242039f3285414cd2e

There exist web sites run by various organisations that allow you to search for Bitcoin transaction data by transaction-ID. These websites are examples of [blockchain explorers](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer). For example you could find details of the above transaction at a number of websites including

- https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/31144ef6faaad902f3ec4e6f6241aa09f9ea08374abb67242039f3285414cd2e
- https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/31144ef6faaad902f3ec4e6f6241aa09f9ea08374abb67242039f3285414cd2e
- https://blockstream.info/tx/31144ef6faaad902f3ec4e6f6241aa09f9ea08374abb67242039f3285414cd2e

and many others

However, any honest recipient only needs the transaction-ID, they don't need you to tell them which blockchain explorer they should be using.

Dishonest recipients will often mis-use technical terms to try and confuse you into paying them more money.